# Is there a way to pass tnsname.ora while launching the oracle sql developer Client via command prompt

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

Is there a way to pass tnsname.ora while launching the oracle sql developer Client via command prompt?

Or is there a way to overwrite the usr directory location where the connection.xml folder is present to another location and pass it via command prompt. The sql developer. Exe - help gives certain parameters that can be passed, conf file and over write directory value.. Can any one let me know how to use those parameter for passing different connection depending on what is being passed in conf file or connection.xml.

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what problem you're trying to solve?  If you were passing a tnsnames.ora file dynamically at startup, that would seem to imply that you'd want a connection in SQL Developer that referenced a TNS alias the might exist or that might point at one of several different databases depending on which tnsnames.ora file was used at startup.  I am hard pressed to imagine a situation where either of those would make a whole lot of sense.  If you are trying to do something else, there is probably an easier way to do it.

Comment: You can set a flag to change the direct your preferences, SQL history, and reports are stored. There's a preference that can be used to specify the folder for your tns file